# GlassFish 4.1 updatetool on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, glassfish, glassfish-4.1

When I am executing the updatetool from the command prompt, I am receiving the following error:

```
Traceback (innermost last):
  File "/usr/local/glassfish-4.1.1/updatetool/vendor-packages/updatetool/common/boot.py", line 283, in init_app_locale
    import wx
  File "wx/__init__.py", line 45, in ?
  File "wx/_core.py", line 4, in ?
 ImportError: libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I can see that libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0 is present and following is the architecture of the libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0:

objdump -f /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0 | grep ^architecture
architecture: i386:x86-64

Answer (score 0):

I could able to successfully execute the updatetool command from glassfish server administration URL.